# Dell XPS 15z (L511z) - Ubuntu 13.04 - Short Battery Life... Any help, ideas, or mods?

Tags: 13.04, laptop, dell, power-management, battery

I presently have a Dell XPS 15z **(L511z) (+ 240GB SanDisk Extreme SSD Upgrade)**.

I also have **Ubuntu Gnome 13.04** installed. My BIOS is at the latest version.

I have the following power-related packages installed: bumblebee, pm-utils, acpi, acpi-call-tools, powernap, powerwake, smartdimmer, and tlp

I use the following boot commands: acpi_backlight=vendor dell_laptop.backlight=0 pcie_aspm=force i915.i915_enable_rc6=1 i915.i915_enable_fbc=1 drm.vblankoffdelay=1 vt.handoff=7 quiet splash acpi_osi=linux

I am only getting **2.5 hours of battery life now**. It's horrible. I was getting 4-6 hours of battery life when I had Ubuntu 12.04 with bumblebee and laptop-mode-tools installed.

My laptop should be getting 5 hours of battery life on average. I can get that in Windows 8 x64 with high-performance mode turned on for the battery mode.

Why can't I get that on Ubuntu any more? I used to be able to, prior to Ubuntu 12.10.

I NEED HELP. I have tried as much research as I could find, no luck.

**Does anyone know how I can get AT LEAST 4 hours of battery, WITHOUT throttling my CPU or dimming my display more than reasonable? Suggestions?**

Comment: Have you updated to the Latest Bios from [to http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/19/DriverDetails/Product/xps-l412z?driverId=38CJN&osCode=W732&fileId=2731104460&languageCode=en&categoryId=BI&dgc=SM&cid=260354&lid=4799792](http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/19/DriverDetails/Product/xps-l412z?driverId=38CJN&osCode=W732&fileId=2731104460&languageCode=en&categoryId=BI&dgc=SM&cid=260354&lid=4799792)

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/is-there-a-power-saving-application-similar-to-jupiter/285681#285681

Answer (score 1):

you can use TLP:  is an advanced power management command line tool for Linux that tries to apply these settings / tweaks for you automatically, depending on your Linux distribution and hardware

http://www.webupd8.org/2013/04/improve-power-usage-battery-life-in.html

Comment: that is been covered http://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/is-there-a-power-saving-application-similar-to-jupiter/285681#285681

Comment: I did read that article in earlier this month. I tried that as noted in the post, but results were at not significant. TLP does help, but not enough. I tweaked TLP a little though, and got a little better results, but I'm only at about 3.75 - 4 hours max hours. I used to be able to get about 5+ hours average with Ubuntu 12.04 with some tweaks, including laptop-mode-tools, as noted in the post. I also get 5+ hours on average, presently, when using Windows 8 x64 with battery settings at high-performance.